# How to join multiple long sentences numbered into multiple lines(notepad ++) (without wrapping)

Tags: notepad++, notepad

I have copied 20 sentences from the document, but when I paste it into notepad ++ it shows 27 lines. How can I process it out into exactly 20 lines on notepad ++(at the beginning of sentences are numbered like this image) Sorry guy for bad english and thank for reading!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\d)`
- Replace with:   # a space
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n)
(?!\d)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a digit after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Wow,that's amazing! I'm so grateful to you.Many blessings to you and your family. :D